# Vector(array) of atomic variables

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, atomic, copy-constructor

I understand that atomic has a copy constructor that's deleted, but what can I do to make this code work? How can I possibly define a copy constructor inside vector for atomic?

```
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::atomic<int>> examp;
    examp.resize(64);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't have a vector of `std::atomic<int>` because it is not copyable or movable, but you can have a vector of unique_ptrs to `atomic<int>`. If you really need a run-time variable-size vector of atomics, this may be a viable alternative. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::atomic<int>>> examp;
    examp.resize(64);   // 64 default unique_ptrs; they point to nothing

    // init the vector with unique_ptrs that actually point to atomics
    for (auto& p : examp) {
        p = std::make_unique<std::atomic<int>>(0);   // init atomic ints to 0
    }

    // use it
    *examp[3] = 5;

    for (auto& p : examp) {
        cout << *p << ' ';
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Growing this while other threads are accessing elements would be data-race UB (on the std::vector control block), and this extra level of indirection is inefficient and only exists to keep C++ happy.  In C++20, you could use `std::atomic_ref` on elements of a `vector<int>`, which you only resize when other threads can't be accessing it.  Or as a new answer points out, if you know the runtime-variable size you need when allocating it, use `vector<atomic<int>> examp(size)`.  You can't `.push_back` or resize, but you can use it.

Answer (score 3):

`std::atomic` is not copyable or movable. As you noted, the copy constructor is deleted but no move constructor is generated. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor:

> If no user-defined move constructors are provided for a class type
>   (struct, class, or union), and all of the following is true:
>
> - there are no user-declared copy constructors;

User-declared means "not added by the compiler" (i.e by `default`). Even though it is a library class, the constructor is user-declared.

The `resize` function for a vector requires that the type either be move-insertable or copy-insertable depending on the overload. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize:

> If the current size is less than count,
>
> 1) additional default-inserted elements are appended
>
> 2) additional copies of value are appended

What you're doing simply won't work.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You could probably have a const array of atomics if you never plan on copying/moving them.

Comment: `std::atomic<int> examp[64]` would be fine, but I do plan on changing the size *eventually*.

Comment: You plan on having run-time or compile-time size of atomics? The compiler can deduce the size if the size is known at compile-time.

Comment: runtime. Depending on user interaction, it'll be anywhere between 32 and 64

Comment: @J.Doe It is unusual to require a dynamic amount of atomics. You might want to explain why you need it

Comment: Depending on the users processor quality, we may change how we calculate our program. The better the quality, the greater the array size for calculations.

Comment: You can of course pick the largest possible size that you plan to support, it's not like 64 ints is a big drain on system resources.

Comment: @PasserBy, One use case is the vector is part of an object, and you want to set the size in the constructor rather than in the definition of the object.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following code in VS 2022 and it works:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::atomic<int>> examp (64);    

}
```

However, as the `std::atomic` type is not copyable or movable, some member functions (such as `resize()`) could not be implemented. For a vector of atomic variables, many member functions impose stricter requirements.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a runtime-variable size but don't need to resize the object after that, you can use `std::vector< atomic<int> > elems(size)` as @Quanbing Luo points out.

Member functions like `.pop_back` and `.push_back` won't compile, even if you've arranged things so it definitely won't exceed its `.capacity()` and have to grow.  But other than that it should work fine.

---

[In C++20, you can use `std::atomic_ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref) to do atomic operations on a plain `int` object, so you can use `std::vector<int>` and

```cpp
  static_assert(std::atomic_ref<int>::required_alignment == alignof(int), "vector elements need to be sufficiently aligned for atomic_ref");
  std::vector<int> examp(size);  // and potentially do whatever non-atomic init before sharing

  examp.resize(size2);

  std::atomic_ref<int> examp3(examp[3]);
  examp3.store(1, std::memory_order_release);
```

Perhaps use a `typedef` or something instead of bare `int` everywhere. And maybe even helper functions for some atomic ops so you don't have to manually construct an `atomic_ref` object in a separate statement.  (Constructing one is free; it'll optimize away as long as you don't keep the `atomic_ref` object around.  It only exists as an API to wrap stuff like [GNU C](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) `__atomic_load_n(int *, int memorder)`, which you could use manually if you don't want to use C++20 features.)

---

Nothing can make it thread-safe to grow or shrink a vector while other threads are accessing elements of it, **so there's no upside to the extra level of indirection in another answer's proposed `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::atomic<int>>> examp;`.**  The `std::vector<unique_ptr>` object itself (typically 3 pointers, .data(), .end() and end-of-allocation) is not atomic, and anything that reallocates the array while another thread is accessing it is a problem.

Writing inefficient code just to keep the compiler happy is kind of at odds with the purpose of using lock-free atomics instead of locking (performance at the expense of simplicity).